# combine if condition with isnan statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to work with an if statement and check if the row values are NaN or not. It turns out to be more difficult that I thought

here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': ['A1', 'B1', 'NaN', 'A1', 'B1','NaN']},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])

def set_perf(row):
    if ("C" in row['key']) & (row['data2']=="NaN"):
        return row['data1']    
    else:        
        return 1

df['NewColumn'] = df.apply(set_perf, axis=1)
```

the output is

```
  key  data1 data2  NewColumn
0   A      0    A1          1
1   B      1    B1          1
2   C      2   NaN          2
3   A      3    A1          1
4   B      4    B1          1
5   C      5   NaN          5
```

The output gives me what I am looking for meaning that I am able to identify the NaN value by adding another condition in the if statement (row['data2']=="NaN")

I have applied exactly the same logic in my original dataset but it didnt work. Here is a snapshot

```
      NewPerfColumn sec_type tran_type LDI Bucket  Alpha vs Markit
0             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN      3283.400526
1             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN      6710.130364
2             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN      3266.912122
3             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN    113401.946471
4             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN      1938.494818
5             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN      9505.724498
6             1.000     GOVT        BB        NaN       192.196620
7             1.000  MUNITAX       RRP        NaN    -97968.750000
```

when I add (row['LDI Bucket']=="NaN" ) in the if condition the value "NaN" is not recognizable.
here are the distinct values of column "LDI Bucket"

```
data['LDI Bucket'].unique()
array([nan, u'0-3m', u'3-6m', u'6-9m', u'9m-1y'], dtype=object)
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Oops, you are mistaking `NaN` with `"NaN"`, one is a float and the other, a string. _Very_ different.

Comment: Don't use `apply` unless you are absolutely sure there is no straightforward vectorised method. Here `set_perf` adds unnecessary complexity; learn how [`.loc` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) works (for example), hundreds (if not thousands) of examples on SO & beyond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have I missed anything?

Yes. In your MWE, you've represented `NaN` as a string... it's not. It's a float, and represents a certain mathematical quantity that is not equal to any other quantity, including itself.

`"NaN" == "NaN"` is true, but `NaN == NaN` is not. This is the underlying cause of your issue.

Here's the naive fix, use `pd.isnull` to test for NaNness.

```
def set_perf(row):
    if ("C" in row['key']) and pd.isnull(row['data2']): 
        return row['data1']    
    else:        
        return 1
```

And here's the better fix, use `np.where` and vectorize your function.

```
df['NewColumn'] = np.where(
    df['key'].str.contains('C') & df['data2'].isnull(), df['data1'], 1
)
```

Comment: @coldspeed  i did try method one before (np.isnan) but i get an error          results[i] = func(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in set_perf
TypeError: ('Not implemented for this type', u'occurred at index 37')      . I ll try method 2 and get back to you  . Thank you

Comment: @SBad Ah, probably the & vs and issue. Yes, the second one would work and would be much better.

Comment: @coldspeed method 2 works fine. thank you!  npwhere is the key here. however npwhere might not be the best solution for a nested if condition thats why I tend to use df.apply

Comment: @SBad man do me a favor, accept this well explained answer, rather than mine poor answer

Comment: @Wen Sorry man, was not fighting for accepts... am perfectly happy if you get it too. Just wanted to inform OP that they can only accept one answer

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am not too, we know each other such a long time , no worry about it. For me, I would like left the well explained answer as accepted answer for future visitors :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is `'NaN'`

```
np.where((df.key.apply(lambda x : 'C' in x))&(df['data2']=='NaN'),df['data1'],1)
Out[58]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

If it is `np.NaN`

```
np.where((df.key.apply(lambda x : 'C' in x))&(df['data2'].isnull()),df['data1'],1)
Out[58]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Based on their code I assume they want "str.contains" (in check), not `==`.

Comment: No worries, you can use str.contains.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope , I hope they accept yours , since yours contain more explanation about the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

& is a bitwise and for operations e.g.

```
In [5]: 1 & 3
Out[5]: 1
```

"and" is what you are looking for, so the if line should be:

```
  if ("C" in row['key']) and (row['data2']=="NaN"):
```

Answer (score -1):

You can  use numpy package or if statement like

```
if pd.isnull(row[0]):
  print("do it more")
```

pandas isnull method will handle your Nan value.

Comment: This solution is not complete.